# parent dialog state is changed to invisible but child dialog still stays visible

Tags: java, swing, window, jdialog

In my project code, we are using custom dialogs. I am facing some weird issues with them. 
I have a child dialogue and a parent dialogue.
**Ideally a child dialogue goes to invisible state when we invoke** `parent.setVisible(false)`.

But I am seeing some strange behaviour. 
When I make `parent.setVisible(false)` then still my child dialog remains visible but when I try to get `child.isVisible()` : it gives me false.
Also when I try to invoke `child.setVisible(false)`, again it has no effect in visiblity of parent dialog .

NOTE: I cannot show any code sample due to too much complexity, lenght and other external API issues. Also I tried replicating this using external programs but it works as expected and no issues seen.

I just want to know does anybody knows any scenario in which a child dialog control get loosen up when we make `parent.setVisible(false)`?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know does anybody knows any scenario in which a child
>   dialog control get loosen up when we make parent.setVisible(false)?

- for parent is called setVisible(false) too,
- be sure that you to reuse reduced number of childs, to set DefaultCloseOparation to HIDE or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (by defasult the last container turn off light, but hasn't effect if is there modality between containers)

for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class ModalityAndJDialog {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JDialog dialog1;
    private JDialog dialog2;
    private JButton button = new JButton("Start Swing Timer");
    private JButton button1 = new JButton();
    private JButton button01 = new JButton();
    private JButton button02 = new JButton();
    private Timer timer;

    public ModalityAndJDialog() {
        button.setAction(updateCol());
        frame.setTitle("JFrame");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, updateCol());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    private Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("Show JDialog") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (dialog1 == null) {
                    dialog1 = new JDialog(dialog1, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    dialog1.setTitle("1st. JDialog");
                    dialog1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    button1.setAction(updateCol1());
                    button01.setAction(updateCol01());
                    dialog1.add(button1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    dialog1.add(button01, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    dialog1.pack();
                    dialog1.setSize(400, 300);
                    dialog1.setLocation(250, 250);
                    dialog1.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                        dialog1.setVisible(true);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private Action updateCol01() {
        return new AbstractAction("Hide JDialog") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (dialog1 != null) {
                    dialog1.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private Action updateCol1() {
        return new AbstractAction("Show Child JDialog") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (dialog2 == null) {
                    dialog1.setTitle("2nd. JDialog");
                    dialog2 = new JDialog(frame, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    dialog2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    button02.setAction(updateCol02());
                    dialog2.add(button02, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    dialog2.pack();
                    dialog2.setSize(400, 300);
                    dialog2.setLocation(350, 350);
                    dialog2.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                        dialog2.setVisible(true);
                        if (!frame.isVisible()) {
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private Action updateCol02() {
        return new AbstractAction("Hide JDialog") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (frame != null) {
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                }
                /*if (dialog1 != null) {
                 dialog1.setVisible(false);
                 }*/
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            /*UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());*/
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException ex) {
            System.out.println("[L&F][Exception] " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ModalityAndJDialog();
        });
    }
}
```